# Replace Not with And Not in string

Tags: c#, string

I have string 
A Not B And Not C
I want this string to replace with
A And Not B And Not C.
means I want to replace all "Not" with "And Not" which are not followed by "And" keyword.

Comment: ... what You try?

Comment: I think you want to replace all "Not" with "And Not" which are not PRECEDED by "And" - also you probably want the constraint of "except at the start of the string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's a more engineered solution, but this should do the trick:

`var result = "A Not B And Not C".Replace("Not", "And Not").Replace("And And Not", "And Not")`